# Terminal command to kill Safari

Tags: cmd, terminal, safari, microsoft-edge

I need the terminal command to quit Safari including its tabs. When I use `killall "Safari"`, reopening the Safari retains all the previously opened tabs. This happens only when I close the browser using terminal command. How to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all these types of questions should be posted at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) not StackOverflow.

The “Quit” operation in MacOS is not a signal; it is an Apple Event.
You can send "Quit" event with AppleScript like this:

```
osascript -e "tell application \"Safari\" to quit"
```